# how can I extract number between two strings one is fixed and other is any thing

Tags: c#, regex, string

how can I extract number between two strings one is fixed and other is any thing
EX.
HimyDear139friend
mydear111sayhi1234
imissdear121212
dear123likeorange

i nead to extract the number which is always after dear

Answer (score 6):

Use this expression:

```
string expression = "dear(\d+)";
string myString = "HimyDear139friend mydear111sayhi1234 imissdear121212 dear123likeorange"
MatchCollection matches =  Regex.Matches(myString, expression);
foreach(Match m in macthes)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Aliostad is the correct one, just add the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option to it if you want to catch the `Dear` and `dear` indifferently

```
string expression = @"dear(\d+)";
string myString = "HimyDear139friend mydear111sayhi1234 imissdear121212 dear123likeorange";

MatchCollection matches =  Regex.Matches(myString, expression);
foreach(Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);

Console.WriteLine("Ignoring Case Option Enabled");
matches = Regex.Matches(myString, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Hope that helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
/dear(\d+)/i
```

Comment: This is javascript! OP is after **C#**.

Comment: JavaScript _or_ Perl (and I'm sure more languages than that, if you look hard enough)

Comment: @CodeJockey I do not know Perl. And that was not the point... the point is that the format Regex is in, would not be useful to OP as he clearly tagged his question with C#. This regex expression will not compile.

Comment: @Aliostad I understood the point, and was adding my commentary - no offense intended :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
/dear(\d*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

As you will get about 92873928734 regular expression solutions that all look the same, here is a solution that doesn't use a regular expression:

```
// get start position
int index = str.IndexOf("dear") + 4;
// get digits
string digits = new String(str.Skip(index).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: str.IndexOx() - is this a custom function?   ----- :-P

Comment: This will not find all such cases in the string, would it?

Comment: @Aliostad: You mean that you have multiple occurances in the same string? This will only get the first occurance. You could loop and use the previous index in the `IndexOf` call to get multiple occurances.